# How to control the execution of Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I wants to get the last id from MySQL table and create a cookie with this value in Javascript and PHP. following is my code.

```
if (getCookie("id")=='') {
    last_visitor_id = get_last_visitor();
    deviceID = last_visitor_id++;
    setCookie("id", deviceID , 365);
    $.ajax({
        url:"save_device.php?deviceID="+deviceID+
            "&websiteID="+WebsiteID+
            "&width="+sWidth+
            "&height="+sHeight,
            success:function (datasource) {
                // alert (datasource);
            }
        }
    );  
} else {
    deviceID = getCookie("id");
    alert ("working...." + deviceID);
}


 function get_last_visitor(){
    $.ajax({url:"get_last_visitor.php",success:function(last_visitor){
         // last_visitor++;
         //alert ("Last Visitor ID " + last_visitor);
         return (last_visitor);
    }});
```

}

There is a problem with code. Before it gets the last visitor id it executes the `setCookie` function even though there is no value returned by the `get_last_visitor()` function. Functions return the value after some time, but in the mean time it creates a cookie with NAN.

Can any one suggest some solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function ?

Answer (score 2):

It make no sense to execute `return (last_visitor)` from your ajax call since it is async. The execution flow is not waiting for the ajax call to finish, next line is executed inmetiatly so `get_last_visitor` is returning null ALWAYS.

You can change your code like this to use the success ajax callback to execute your logic

```
if (getCookie("id")==''){
    $.ajax({url:"get_last_visitor.php"})
    .done(function(last_visitor_id) {
        deviceID = last_visitor_id++;
        setCookie("id", deviceID , 365);
        $.ajax({url:"save_device.php?deviceID="+deviceID+"&websiteID="+WebsiteID+"&width="+sWidth+"&height="+sHeight,success:function(datasource){
            // alert (datasource);
        }});    
    });
} else {
    deviceID = getCookie("id");
    alert ("working...." + deviceID);
}
```

Comment: your are right, it always returning null value. can you please suggest some solution ????

Comment: i can see the returned value in firebug, but its not proceeding to the next line. i mean its still not creating the cookie.

Comment: i am getting this error:

TypeError: $.ajax(...).done is not a function

Comment: @user2674341: what jquery version are you using?